# ffmpeg convert rtmp audio/video stream to icecast2 audio/video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, icecast

I've been using this command to convert my public rtmp audio/video stream to a local mp3 audio icecast2 stream, but I have been unable to do the same for both video and audio.

[Audio Only] (This works fine)
`ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://162.142.xx.xxx:xxx/stream -vn -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -f mp3 -content_type audio/mpeg icecast://source:password@192.168.1.xxx:80/live`

I've tried to re-write in order to support video, but I keep hitting dead ends

[Audio & Video Attempt] (this does not work)
`ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://162.142.xx.xxx:xxx/stream -codec:v -f mpeg4 -b:v -f mpeg4 -content_type video/mpeg4 icecast://source:password@192.168.1.xxx:80/live`

When I run this command, it gives me the error below asking for a suitable format.

```
$ ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://162.142.xx.xxx:xxx/stream -codec:v -f mpeg4 -b:v -f mpeg4 -content_type video/mpeg4 icecast://source:password@192.168.1.xxx:80/live
[h264 @ 0x5598ffbb8980] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x5598ffbb8980] mmco: unref short failure
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://162.142.xx.xxx:xxx/stream':
  Metadata:
    |RtmpSampleAccess: true
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1280
    displayHeight   : 720
    fps             : 48
    videokeyframe_frequency: 0
    profile         :
    level           :
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 28117.779000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 327 kb/s
  Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2560 kb/s, 48 fps, 48 tbr, 1k tbn
[NULL @ 0x5598ffb8bec0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'mpeg4'
mpeg4: Invalid argument
```

I am positive that icecast2 can support video streams, however on the few occasions that I was able to actively stream successfully to it, it only showed an empty video embed.

I've re-written the command for AV multiple times while referencing ffmpeg documentation, however my above attempt seems to be the closest (concept-wise) that I have gotten.

What flags/formatting might I be missing which are causing the stream not to work?

Comment: Instead of `-codec:v -f mpeg4`, I think you meant `-codec:v libx264`, as currently you're not actually specifying the codec.  And then for the format, I think you should use `-f mpegts`.  Content type should probably be `video/mpeg`.  Sorry I don't have a way to test right now, but if you're still stuck, reply to this comment and I'll get back to you tomorrow.  I haven't sent video through Icecast in a long time, and I used Ogg previously which is officially supported.  But in theory if your player is compatible, MPEG-TS should sync and work for the container.